# Updating table with non-values based on most recent date

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following table with data from GA in BigQuery

```
userid  visitid purchase_date
GH8932  12345   2017-04-09
GH8932  12346   null
GH8932  12347   null
GH8932  12348   null
GH8932  12349   2017-05-30
GH8932  12350   null
GH8932  12351   null
GH8932  12352   2017-06-07
GH8932  12353   null
GH8932  12354   2017-06-30
GH8932  12355   null
GH8932  12356   null
```

I want to fill all the nulls with the purchase_date.

The current query I use (given below)

```
SELECT
 userid,
 visitid,
FIRST_VALUE(purchase_date IGNORE NULLS) OVER (
  PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY visitid
  ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND
  UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS purchase_date
FROM x;
```

gives me something like this

```
userid  visitid purchase_date
GH8932  12345   2017-04-09
GH8932  12346   2017-05-30
GH8932  12347   2017-05-30
GH8932  12348   2017-05-30
GH8932  12349   2017-05-30
GH8932  12350   2017-06-07
GH8932  12351   2017-06-07
GH8932  12352   2017-06-07
GH8932  12353   2017-06-30
GH8932  12354   2017-06-30
GH8932  12355   null 
GH8932  12356   null
```

Any suggestions on how I can fill the last 2 nulls with the final purchase_date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  userid,
  visitid,
  IFNULL(FIRST_VALUE(purchase_date IGNORE NULLS) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY visitid
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
  FIRST_VALUE(purchase_date IGNORE NULLS) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY visitid DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) AS purchase_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'GH8932' userid, 12345 visitid, '2017-04-09' purchase_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GH8932', 12346, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GH8932', 12347, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GH8932', 12348, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GH8932', 12349, '2017-05-30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GH8932', 12350, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GH8932', 12351, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GH8932', 12352, '2017-06-07' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GH8932', 12353, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GH8932', 12354, '2017-06-30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GH8932', 12355, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GH8932', 12356, NULL 
)
SELECT
  userid,
  visitid,
  IFNULL(FIRST_VALUE(purchase_date IGNORE NULLS) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY visitid
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
  FIRST_VALUE(purchase_date IGNORE NULLS) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY visitid DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) AS purchase_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`
ORDER BY userid, visitid
```